# How to rewrite or redirect in subdirectory with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have difficulties to understand how htaccess rewrite / redirect is working. I have been trough already more than 20 article about it but I don't catch the logic and the syntax of how to write rules properly.

I currently have a server with public_html folder
We have our main site under the subfolder /site  , this is a wordpress site
We have other site (also a wordpress site) we use for e-learning under the subfolder /training

I need to make our site (domain.com) to point to /public_html/site while having domain.com/learning to point to public_html/training

I have tried to understad how queries in htaccess are working such as RewriteCond or RewriteRule

Here is my current code:

```
    # Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php


# File modified on Sun Mar 30 01:22:23 2014 by server
# For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives
# php_value max_execution_time 90

# BlueHost.com
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on



#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/


# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1

# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site_en/index.html [L]


# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change domain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
# Change 'site to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learning/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'site' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /learning/$1
# Change domain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'site' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ learning/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will need to be added to the .htaccess file in the public_html folder of your hosting account.

You will need to insert the following code block and make modifications as noted in the (#) comments.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change domain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
# Change 'site to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'site' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1
# Change domain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'site' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/index.html [L]
```

Repeat Same for Learning domain .

Visitors to your Web site will not be able to tell that your main domain is using a subdirectory, they will still see the Web site address as

> http://www.domain.com/index.html.

**Note :**

> Please note that this will not work with some website software. You
>   may also need to modify the $base_url, $live_site or other
>   configuration settings to finish the process.

Since you mentioned that your case is WordPress , don't forget to have a look at this too

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

**Update :**

```
RedirectMatch 301 /learning/(.*) /training/$1

# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change domain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
# Change 'site to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'site' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1
# Change domain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'site' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I talked a bit quick. Our learning website is protect with a htpasswd. Putting the two code one after each other make that the main site is not accessible anymore without inputting password.

Comment: @chris , why you taken back the answer verification mate ?

Comment: because it doesn't work. I posted back in the initial topic with my current htaccess.

Comment: Mate , you have many overriding htaccess , remove the entire code and paste the one i gave alone and modify that with your domain names and check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125082/discussion-between-raja-gopal-and-chris).